# Shopify help: Adding Price on line item properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, shopify, liquid

I added a custom properties in Shopify product page. I would like to add price in each properties in the dropdown of the Frame Size.

```
<div class="product-form__controls-group digital-print">
<div class="selector-wrapper product-form__item">
<label for="options" style="margin-top: 10px;">FRAMES</label>
<select id="options" name="properties[Frame Size]" required class="required product-form__input">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Size</option>
<option value="3x3">3x3</option>
  <option value="6x3">6x3</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By default it is not possible in Shopify, you need to develop app or use any 3rd party app for it

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify, a product has 1 or more variants. Assuming you have a variant with  size option of 3x3, then it has a price. Assuming you have another variant with a size option of 6x3, it too has a price. You get at prices with Liquid, using the *variant.price*, and so for you, it is important to dump the current variant price into your option element in HTML. Note that selling frames this way is a PITA. The best way is to price your frame out as per inch, gather how many inches a frame is, and then put that many units in the cart as a quantity. So a frame sells for $1.50 per inch, therefore you put 12" in the cart for a 3x3 size, or 18" in the cart for a 6x3 frame. You can then sell any sized frame, and simplify your life. The one complication with this is when you want to sell 2 or more. It is up to you to multiply the number of inches correctly and accommodate for change at the cart. Good luck.